# Any examples of turing-complete GPL's in MPS

Tags: mps

Could you please provide me with examples of open-sourced Turing complete general-purpose language(s) developed under MPS platform? (For further Studying).

Comment: This discussion may help you: http://tomassetti.me/interview-to-vaclav-pech-on-jetbrains-mps-the-community-and-the-future/ A small discussion about MPS (What is going on and what plan for future)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look three OSS implementations at the moment:

1. BaseLanguage (Java) - bundled with MPS itself
2. mbeddr C (C) - http://mbeddr.com/
3. JavaScript - https://github.com/mar9000/ecmascript4mps

Vaclav